# Electromagnetic radiation of dipole in the frequency domain

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform, dipole

Recently I've met a formaula that says the radiation power of a dipole in the frequency domain is $I(\omega) = |\omega^2P(\omega)|^2$, where $\omega$ is the frequency of the radiation and $P(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of the polarization $P(t)$. And Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics was cited there. I am confused because $I(t) = |E(t)|^2$ and $E(t) \propto \frac{d^2P}{dt^2}$ and $P(t)\propto sin(\omega t)$, so $E(\omega)\propto \omega^2 P(\omega)$. But $I(\omega) \ne E^2(\omega)$ but should be $E(\omega) \ast E(\omega)$ where $\ast$ indicates the convolution. So I don't understand how to get $I(\omega) = |\omega^2P(\omega)|^2$. I am not familiar with Jackson's book and I couldn't find the origin derivation there. Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $I(\omega) = E^2(\omega)$. A multiplication in the frequency domain [is a convolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) in the *time domain*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this makes me even more confused. $I(t)=E(t)^2$ is written in the textbook, so, I really don't know now.